# efficiently computing a sum of products of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $F$ be a prime finite field. Let $d$ be a power of two dividing $p-1$. Suppose I have $d$ pairs of univariate polynomials $f_i,g_i$ over $F$ for $i=1,\ldots,d$. All have degree less than $d$.
I want to compute the coefficients of the polynomial

$$h(X)\triangleq \sum_{i=1}^d f_i(X) g_i(X) $$

I can do this in $O(d^2\cdot \log d)$ operations by computing each product using FFT techniques in time $O(d\log d)$ and then summing the $d$ products.

Can I do this in time $O(d^2)$ somehow? Is there an indication that would contradict some conjectured lower bound?

I don't mind computing $h$ in any basis, doesn't have to be the monomial basis.

Comment: A very brief remark: Restating your problem as the inner product of two vectors of polynomials, it is clear that a $O(d^2)$ algorithm implies a $O(d^3)$ algorithm for matrix-vector product with polynomial matrices. I cannot find a reference where it is explicitly written, but all the complexity results I know of for polynomial matrices use FFT-based techniques, and thus have the $\log d$ factor in the complexity. *Cf* for instance this [recent paper](https://hal-unilim.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01683632v2) for references. Of course, I do not claim any lower bound though...